# Url stored in string resource turns into number in Andrioid

Tags: java, android

I stored an url on the strings.xml file to show it in my app, it is something like this:

```
<string name="url_stat">https://my.websyte.net/url_stramin/api/v1/</string>
```

When I want to use it in java I call it this way:

```
textView.setText(R.string.url_stat+"key/");
Log.i("KEY",R.string.url_stat+"key/");
```

But what I get is this text:

> 2131623976key/

for some reason this string turns into a number, why? how to avoid it?

Comment: `R.string.api_stat` is not a `String` but a reference to one... Isn't there something like `getResources().getString(R.string.api_stat);` in Android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That number is the numerical identifier (the resource value) you should do the following

```
textview.setText(getString(R.string.url_stat) + "key/");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the CDATA Tag in your xml? Something like this:

```
<string name="url_stat"><![CDATA[https://my.websyte.net/url_stramin/api/v1/]]></string>
```

I'm not sure if it works, I haven't tested